# Scala - getting a callback when an external process exits

Tags: scala

I'm looking to replace a lot of my perl with scala. One of the things I tend to do a lot is call binaries (usually compiled C++, but could be java, other perl scripts, q scripts, etc) provided to me by other teams at my company.

For example, to do some complex math, I'd start one of the foreign binaries, then pipe my inputs to it. I'd then listen to its `stdout` stream for results, and `stderr` stream for diagnostic messages. In perl, I'd do this using a `POE::Wheel::Run` widget. I've come up with something analogous (and much nicer) in scala, but I'd like to make it more robust. It's a little wrapper around a `ProcessIO` object. It looks like this:

```
class Exe(command: String, out: String => Unit, err: String => Unit) {

    import scala.sys.process._
    import scala.io._
    import java.io._
    import scala.concurrent._

    val inputStream = new SyncVar[OutputStream];

    val process = Process(command).run(
        new ProcessIO(
            stdin => inputStream.put(stdin),
            stdout => Source.fromInputStream(stdout).getLines.foreach(out),
            stderr => Source.fromInputStream(stderr).getLines.foreach(err)));

    def write(s: String): Unit = synchronized {
        inputStream.get.write((s + "\n").getBytes)
    }

    def close(): Unit = {
        inputStream.get.close
    }
}
```

I'd then use it like this:

```
val exe = new Exe("tr [a-z] [A-Z]", 
                  out => println("o: " + out), 
                  err => println("e: " + err))
exe.write("lower")
exe.close()
```

Which prints out:

```
o: LOWER
```

This gets me 90% there, but what would be nice would be to get a callback when the process exits. It may exit because I've closed the input stream and its internal loop stops, it may exit on its own, or it may exit because I've killed it. In the callback, it would be good to know why it stopped, and the exit code.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to go about this, any help would be appreciated (and any edits to the above code are, of course, welcome - I'm a bit of a noob).

I'm using 2.9.0.1

Comment: Personally, I think it sucks that `Process` doesn't have some kind of `isFinished` polling method. That's one thing I'd change, though the solution provided by didierd seems more like what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wait for the end of a process calling `exitValue`. You might do that in a separate thread, in which the callback will happen. Maybe class `Process` could be pimped thus:

```
import scala.concurrent.ops.spawn
implicit def ProcessWithCallback(p: Process) {
  def whenTerminatedDo(callback: Int => Unit) = spawn{
    val exitValue = p.exitValue; callback(p)
  }
}
```

You could then use that in `Exe` as you like.

The `Process` class given by the JVM and wrapped by `scala.sys.Process` is really rather feable, it will be hard not to block a thread

Comment: There's no way to get a callback without a separate thread blocked or polling (no matter what support `process` provided). That said, polling would have been nice.

Comment: @Daniel. My issue with the the JVM Process is that because it does not provide such a method (not even a timed wait!), we cannot do better than using a Thread. If the Process API was bigger (in java), providing a method such as the one discussed here, the JVM could make use of OS-specific features in some implementations  and do the thread stuff by itself if need be in others. I'm not familiar with system programming, but I remember SIGCHLD under UNIX, no waiting thread was needed - nor really available in those days ;-).  Do I miss something?

Comment: SIGCHLD is an interruption. There are no interruptions in the JVM model. Well, [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/i-signalhandling/) suggests there's a non-standard way about it. Anyway, the problem is the lack of a standard interrupt mechanism.

Comment: @Daniel. I think we misunderstand. I was regretting some feature (smth. akin to addShutdownHook in class Process) lacking in java API. My idea was that a JVM implementation to make use of SIGCHLD to implement efficiently some "addShutdownHook" method in class java.lang.Process, not that such a thing would go beyond implementation internals, or could be done in the scala api. Or is even that impossible?

Comment: I'm not an expert in JVM, but from my understanding of it, there's no standard way to interrupt execution in a thread to run an interrupt handler. To do any such callback, a thread would _have_ to be created somewhere. On the other hand, to retrieve an exit status requires a thread (one has to fork, exec the child and have the parent wait on it), so I suppose there _is_ a place for such hook already.

Answer (score 3):

updated version using `spawn` to create a new thread that blocks and waits for the exit code

```
class Exe(command:String, out:String=>Unit, err:String=>Unit, onExit:Int=>Unit) {

    import scala.sys.process._
    import scala.io._
    import java.io._
    import scala.concurrent._
    import scala.concurrent.ops.spawn

    val inputStream = new SyncVar[OutputStream];

    val process = Process(command).run(
        new ProcessIO(
            stdin => inputStream.put(stdin),
            stdout => Source.fromInputStream(stdout).getLines.foreach(out),
            stderr => Source.fromInputStream(stderr).getLines.foreach(err)));

    spawn { onExit(process.exitValue()) }

    def write(s:String):Unit = synchronized {
        inputStream.get.write((s + "\n").getBytes)
    }

    def close():Unit = {
        inputStream.get.close
    }
}
```

can use like this

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch

val latch = new CountDownLatch(1)

val exe = new Exe("tr [a-z] [A-Z]",
        out => println("o: " + out), 
        err => println("e: " + err), 
        code=> {println(code) ; latch.countDown() })
exe.write("lower") 
exe.close()

latch.await
```

prints

```
o: LOWER
0
```

thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered spawning a new thread which will then call the blocking method process.exitValue()?  You can then call your callback.