# How can I supply input for an external command?

Tags: scala

It is to my understanding that Scala can run system commands and receive their output. I am working on writing a web client for a system command that I have, so that being said I need to perform the command, receive the output, based on the output I can give it a command. I want to keep doing this until the user kills the command. I have read a bit about ProcessIO and I have gotten as far as getting the command to run from scala and receiving the output, but how can I give it input?

**EDIT:** What I am looking for is, I call a command with scala. The command I call asks for a input, the user supplies the input to the scala program with then passes that to the called program.

*An Example:*

Scala Program -> Calls System Program -> System Program ask for username and password -> Scala Program program then asks for username and password from user and user supplies input -> Scala program passes inputs to System Program.

I would like to keep the process alive while feeding it input.

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think all you need is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195051/scala-getting-a-callback-when-an-external-process-exits

Comment: Consider updated answer to this question. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from your question if you intend for the user to supply inputs with something other than stdin to the console.  While I suspect you'd like this to be "fully contained" in the Scala program, I haven't been able to work that out yet.  However, if using the console is acceptable, here's an example of a simple Scala program that asks for a username/password and and another Scala program that starts it and uses `Process.run(true)` to wire the invoked program's out/err to the console while the input can be supplied to the console.

SimpleProgram to test taking inputs:

```
package so

import java.util.Scanner

object SimpleProgram extends App {

  def getInput(prompt: String): Option[String] = {
    print( s"$prompt: " )
    val sc = new Scanner(System.in)
    sc.hasNextLine match {
      case true => val out = sc.nextLine
        if( out.length > 1 ) Some(out) else None
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  while( true ) {
    (getInput("username"), getInput("password")) match {
      case (Some(u), Some(p)) => println( s"Logged in as $u" ); System.exit(0)
      case _ => println( "Invalid input.  Please try again." )
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the program calling ProcessBuilder( where the classpath won't work w/o alterations ):

```
package so

import scala.sys.process._

object ProcessBuilderTest extends App {

  val classpath = "<path to>/scala-library.jar:./classes"
  val pb = Process("java", Seq("-cp", classpath, "so.SimpleProgram" ))
  pb.run(true) // all the magic happens here.
}
```

In this case, the `Process` is basically just wrapping the invoked program in a `ProcessBuilder`.  I haven't been able to work out using a `ProcessIO` with supplied methods to both eat the appropriate chars, and still kill the streams etc.  My guess is that looking at the working `run(true)` case would be instructive.

Here's an example of the console logging from running the latter with a corrected classpath:

```
username: foo
password: 
Invalid input.  Please try again.
username: foo
password: bar
Logged in as foo
```

I'm using "java" to run the Scala code because I don't have Scala installed on my mac other than through Eclipse.  From Eclipse, `ProcessBuilderTest` was run from the project directory with both classes, and the output directory set to "classes" instead of "bin".

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following example with redirection,

```
import scala.sys.process._
import java.io.File

"""echo -e hello\nworld""" #> new File("hello") !

new File ("hello") #> """grep world -c""" !!
```

which delivers `1`.

This writes an echoed string onto an *output* file; next the now *input* file is redirected to a system command.

**Update**

Command

```
"""echo -e hello\nworld""" #> """grep world -c""" !!
```

uses redirection and delivers result as a string. This avoids intermediate files.

Comment: So with this solution, I would have the scala program write the user input to a file, which I would then need a middle man process to open the file take the input and supply it to the system program?

Comment: would this kill the processes?