# Construct a new scala program on the fly and run it after construction

Tags: scala

I am planning to write a service that

1. receive request from user
2. construct another program accordingly
3. run the new constructed one as a another process & get its output and error
4. get notified in the service about the exit of construct program

I need a new process instead of a thread because the new program are always heavy loaded and may corrupt the JVM.

And I think [Scala - getting a callback when an external process exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195051/scala-getting-a-callback-when-an-external-process-exits) is quite similar to my requirements except that it is calling a existing program.

Is it possible in Scala? What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Just from a top-level view, your idea sounds exactly like what a shell already does. Why not use one of the popular shells, e.g. bash?

Comment: Have you checked out [Ideone](https://ideone.com/)? They have Scala support; as long as you can get a connection to their server, you may be able to use their [Sphere Engine online compiler](http://sphere-engine.com/features) to do this via an API.

Comment: Depending on how dynamic you want the solution to be, you might be able to do it without code generation, so it really depends on the scope of your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The first part about user input and program code generation seems like compiler or translator.

There are many tools that help to implement translators or compilers in Java and Scala ecosystem.

- [ANLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
- [Parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2)
- [more and more](http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators)

The result of construction is scala source code file.
One approach to run this code on Linux is shell scripting.

For example

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
object HelloWorld extends App {
  println("Hello, world!")
} 
HelloWorld.main(args)
```

For running you could call shell commands from main program. Something like this:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val cmd = "uname -a" // Your command
val output = cmd.!! // Captures the output
```

Please see [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.sys.process.package) for details about scala.sys.process